# How to write a dictionary with numpy array in a file

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this: `

```
d = {1: array([ 1.,  1., 0., 1.]),2: array([ 0.,  1., 0., 1.]), 3:
        array([ 1.,  0., 0., 1.]), 4: array([ 1.,  0., 1., 1.])}`
```

I want to write all the values:

```
 ([ 1.,  1., 0., 1.], [ 0.,  1., 0., 1.], 
  [ 1.,  0., 0., 1.], [ 1.,  0., 1., 1.])
```

in a .tsv file. Each value in a column, in this example I would have 4 columns with 4 rows.

This is what I want in the file:

> 1 0 1 1
>
> 1 1 0 0
>
> 0 0 0 1
>
> 1 1 1 1

each numpy array is printed in a different column.

The code that I have gives me all values in the same column:

```
f = open("Result.tsv", "wb")
for key, value in d.items():
    np.savetxt(f, value, delimiter=',')
f.close()
```

Comment: Please don't mask the built in dict with your own. I changed the variable name to `d`

Comment: Thank you! I'm new at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way might be to format your array to be 2d rather than a dict of 1d columns:

```
out = np.empty((4, 4))
for colnb, col in d.items():
    out[:, colnb-1] = col
with open("Result.tsv", 'wb') as f:
    np.savetxt(f, out, delimiter=',')
```

This way, you let the numpy `savetxt` function handle all the work

Comment: This code throws an exception `IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 4`

Comment: @Oz123: You're absolutely right: I forgot the 0-indexing. Corrected it now (although this is more to give an idea than anything ressembling a robust implementation). Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

This gives you almost what you wanted:

```
with open('Result.csv', 'w') as f:
    for k, v in d.items():
        f.write(str(v)[1:-1]+'\n')



$ cat Result.csv
 1.  1.  0.  1.
 0.  1.  0.  1.
 1.  0.  0.  1.
 1.  0.  1.  1.
```

This goes the extra step and removes the decimal point:

```
with open('Result.csv', 'w') as f:
    for k, v in d.items():
        f.write(str(map(int, v))[1:-1]+'\n')
```

Note also that if you are already writing this as a binary file, which is input for another program you can do the following (but this does not give you the text format you showed). And finally you do this:

```
with open('Result.csv', 'w') as f:
    for k, v in d.items():
        v.tofile(f, sep=',', format='%d')
        f.write('\n')
```